# Feature Extraction from an audio file using python

Tags: scipy, svm, pattern-recognition, feature-extraction

I am writing a chord-recognizer for a school project. I have to extract features from an mp3 file and use SVM with chord labels.

How can I extract frequencies from an audio file.

Is there any scipy package which could get me beat synchronous chroma.

Answer (score 0):

The decoding becomes much easier even using a home-grown tool if to get some raw stream (including WAV file which is simply a raw stream and an envelope around it). Under a usual Unix-like, you can do it e.g. with `mpg123 -s`, `mplayer -ao pcm:fast:file=$outfile` and so on. But I doubt you can find a library which eventually supports all compressed audio formats.

(Also, SoX is good to convert between all uncompressed formats.)

Comment: How can I get features from a wav file?

Comment: You can use any spectral analysis tool, there are quite many of them. I won't suggest any without knowing your circumstances, I've only deduced the task to combination of two simpler ones.

Comment: thanks for the help :) 
I want make a chromagram which is used to identify musical notes. I think there's a chroma toolbox for matlab but I can't seem to find anything like that for python.

Comment: As already written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20748186/2812618) the [Bregman Audio-Visual Information Toolbox](http://bregman.dartmouth.edu/bregman/) gives you a chromagram analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read wave files with python's [wave](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) package. Probably the easiest way to get out frequencies is by taking the FFT ([`numpy.fft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft)) and finding peaks in the output. You'll want to time-box your FFT calls to something that makes sense (windows where the pitches are consistent), or else you'll be looking at a bunch of frequency patterns on top of each other.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider computing a chromagram, which is just like a spectrogram but with the musical notes in the Y axis instead of frequencies. The Librosa python library has a built-in function to compute it. https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.chroma_stft.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for my friend, is **Librosa**. It's perfect for Audio feature extraction and manipulation. **It has a separate submodule for features**. You can extract features at the lowest levels and their documentation has some very easy to understand tutorials.

Here's the link to their website. Along with a sample code

https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html

```
import librosa
audio_file = 'your_audio_file.wav'
signal , sampling_rate = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=16000)
print(type(signal), type(sampling_rate)
len(signal), sampling_rate
```