# extracting pitch features from audio file

Tags: python, audio, scipy, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract pitch features from an audio file which I would use for a classification problem. I am using python(scipy/numpy) for classification.

I think I can get frequency features using `scipy.fft` but I don't know how to approximate musical notes using frequencies. I researched a bit and found that I need to get chroma features which map frequencies to `12` bins for notes of a chromatic scale.

I think there's a chroma toolbox for matlab but I don't think there's anything similiar for python.

How should I go forward with this? 
Could anyone also suggest reading material I should look into?

Answer (score 4):

You can map frequencies to musical notes:

[image: n=12*log_2(f/Cp)+69]

with [image: n] being the midi note number to be calculated, [image: f] the frequency and [image: Cp] the chamber pitch (in modern music 440.0 Hz is common).

As you may know a single frequency doesn't make a musical pitch. "Pitch" arises from the sensation of the fundamental of harmonic sounds, i.e. sounds that mainly consist of integer multiples of one single frequency (= the fundamental).

If you want to have Chroma Features in Python, you can use the [Bregman Audio-Visual Information Toolbox](http://digitalmusics.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/bregman/). Note that chroma features don't give you information about the octave of a pitch, so you just get information about the [pitch class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_class).

```
from bregman.suite import Chromagram
audio_file = "mono_file.wav"
F = Chromagram(audio_file, nfft=16384, wfft=8192, nhop=2205)
F.X # all chroma features
F.X[:,0] # one feature
```

The general problem of extracting pitch information from audio is called [pitch detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks a lot... Could you also recommend reading material or books on pitch detection or application of dsp to music in general?

Comment: As an general introduction to a wide range of computer music issues C. Roads _The Computer Music Tutorial_ (1994, Cambridge: MIT Press) is a very accessible and comprehensive (>1000 pages) reference book. For me the 1st part of M. Müllers _Information Retrieval for Music and Motion_ (2007, Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer) was great (less comprehensive, more up-to-date, more technical). If you are interested in a particular topic, the [procceedings of ISMIR](http://www.ismir.net/proceedings/) are a rich seam of information. Others may give you other (and better?) references. I'd be interested too.

Comment: Pitch IS the fundamental frequency. The harmonics comprise the timbre (pronounced tamber). For example, a flute and a violin can play the same pitch (fundamental frequency), but their timbre is the harmonic frequency characteristics that make them sound different.

Comment: I think, pitch and timbre are no "physical-acoustical" facts, but rather psychoacoustical effects. That's why I wanted stress, that "pitch" arises from sensation of the fundamental and it's not the fundamental itself. Would you agree with that?

Comment: I have to agree with Frank Zalkow here.  Non-harmonic/non-periodic sounds, even modulated noise bursts, can have perceived pitch, so the fundamental frequency is clearly not everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can try reading the literature on pitch detection, which is quite extensive.  Generally autocorrelation-based methods seem to work pretty well; frequency-domain or zero-crossing methods are less robust (so FFT doesn't really help much).  A good starting point may be to implement one of these two algorithms:

- YAAPT, from: Stephen A. Zahorian and Hongbing Hu, "A spectral-temporal method for robust fundamental frequency tracking", J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 123, 4559 (2008).  http://bingweb.binghamton.edu/~hhu1/paper/Zahorian2008spectral.pdf and MATLAB code here: http://ws2.binghamton.edu/zahorian/yaapt.htm
- YIN, from:  De Cheveigné, A., Kawahara, H. "YIN, a fundamental frequency estimator for speech and music", J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 111, 1917-1930 (2002).  http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf

As far as off-the-shelf solutions, check out  [Aubio](http://aubio.org/), C code with python wrapper, several pitch-extraction algorithms available including YIN and multiple-comb.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) About aubio, I am finding implementing examples on this page http://aubio.org/doc/latest/examples.html a little difficult. I can't find the methods they've used in their examples in the library and there isn't enough documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use 3rd party libraries (at least as a reference for how other people accomplished this):

Extracting musical information from sound, a presentation from PyCon 2012, shows how to use the AudioNest Python API:

- [Demo of pitch detection in action](http://youtu.be/bGWytn-Ff9E?t=13m48s)
- [Some background explanation](http://youtu.be/bGWytn-Ff9E?t=12m37s)

Here is the relevant EchoNest documentation:

- [Track API Methods](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html)
- Detailed [Analyze Documentation](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/_static/AnalyzeDocumentation.pdf)

Relevant excerpt:

> *pitch content* is given by a “chroma” vector, corresponding to the
>   12 pitch classes C, C#, D to B, with values ranging from 0 to 1 that
>   describe the relative dominance of every pitch in the chromatic scale.
>   For example a C Major chord would likely be represented by large
>   values of C, E and G (i.e. classes 0, 4, and 7). Vectors are
>   normalized to 1 by their strongest dimension, therefore noisy sounds
>   are likely represented by values that are all close to 1, while pure
>   tones are described by one value at 1 (the pitch) and others near 0.

EchoNest does the analysis on their servers. They provide free API keys for non-commercial use.

If EchoNest is not an option, I would look at the open-source [aubio project](http://aubio.org/). It has python bindings, and you can examine the source to see how [they accomplished pitch detection](https://github.com/piem/aubio/blob/master/examples/aubiopitch.c).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting vid :)