# converting stft to chroma and plotting the result

Tags: python, audio, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to convert stft of a wav file into chromagram.

Here's my code :-

```
def stft(x,fs,framesize,hopsize):
    frame = int(framesize*fs)
    hop = int(hopsize*fs)
    w = scipy.hamming(frame)
    X = scipy.array([scipy.fft(w*x[i:i+frame])]) 
                                   for i in range(0,len(x)-frame,hop)
    return X
```

Here's the code for chromagram :-

```
def chromagram(x,fs,framesize,hopsize):
    X = stft(x,fs,framesize,hopsize)
    chroma = np.fmod(np.round(np.log2(X / 440) * 12), 12)
    return chroma
```

When I calculate fft I get an array with complex values so I have to cast the result to float before calculating chroma. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Also, How do I plot the result?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that works the way to do it. In `X` you have the complex-valued STFT. You can get its magnitude values with `np.abs(X)`. Did you want to apply [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748186/2812618)? This was to convert frequencies to musical notes, but in `X` there are no frequencies. You can get the the corresponding frequencies with `np.fft.fftfreq(framesize, 1.0/fs)`.

If you don't want to use the [Bregman Audio-Visual Information Toolbox](http://bregman.dartmouth.edu/bregman/) for Chroma Features, and want to implement them for you own, you could port the [Matlab Chroma Toolbox](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/resources/MIR/chromatoolbox/). I think they use filterbanks instead of the FFT. Down on this page you find references where Chroma Features are explained in detail.

Anyway, if you have Chroma Features, you can plot them like any 2-dimensional array with [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
X = np.random.random((30, 30))
plt.imshow(X)
plt.show()
```

[image: random imshow example]

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing that up ! 
I thought the result of stft were frequencies. Also,  I did use the bregman suite but I am not sure if the results I am getting are correct. I used a song which is in key of 'C' as the input but the chromagram results were showing intensity in C# region instead of C. I used another package called librosa for chromagram and I saw intensity in the C part of the chromagram. So I am a little confused. I feel I should try my own implementation to get a better grasp of concepts.

Comment: The STFT contains complex values: the real part is the amplitude of the cosine component and the imaginary part is the amplitude of the sine component. So the values correspond to amplitude and phase of a given time/frequency window. If a C major chord shows intensity in the C# region, it could be, that the chamber pitch is lower than the one given to the chromagram analyzer.

Comment: Do you know how can I set the chamber frequency to 440? I am not sure if it's a function parameter to bregman.features.Chromagram.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but it seems you can give the parmater `lo`, that is a quarter note below C2, thus midi note number 15.5. `440 * 2^((15.5-49)/12)=63.544398327975024`, so I think `Chromagram(..., lo=63.544398327975024)` should give you a a chromagram analyzer with chamber pitch 440.0 Hz. But as I said, I am not completly sure...