# How can I get Frequency, pitch, lowdness, etc of audio in python vlc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, vlc, python-vlc

There really doesn't seem to be any function to get these values

```
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer(path/to/file.mp3)
p.play()
```

here I need to get the frequency, pitch and other properties of sound. I am not sure if this is possible using vlc-python, any other solution will also be of help

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need an additional library to achieve what you want.
Here's a video tutorial on how to build an audio spectrum analyzer with Python:
https://youtu.be/AShHJdSIxkY

This was final --python2-- code from a commenter on that video (thanks user Hey Jose!)

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#%matplotlib tk

CHUNK = 4000
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

chosen_device_index = -1
for x in xrange(0,p.get_device_count()):
    info = p.get_device_info_by_index(x)
    #print p.get_device_info_by_index(x)
    if info["name"] == "pulse":
        chosen_device_index = info["index"]
        print "Chosen index: ", chosen_device_index


stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
 channels=CHANNELS,
 rate=RATE,
 input_device_index=chosen_device_index,
 input=True,
 output=True,
 frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
 )
 
plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, CHUNK)
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
data_int16 = struct.unpack(str(CHUNK) + 'h', data)
line, = ax.plot(x, data_int16)
#ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([-2**15,(2**15)-1])

while True:
 data = struct.unpack(str(CHUNK) + 'h', stream.read(CHUNK))
 line.set_ydata(data)
 fig.canvas.draw()
 fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

This tutorial uses PyAudio (https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/)

I haven't done the tutorial yet but reading the sample code they seem to take the approach of reading the audio stream in chunks and mapping the bytes to the y-axis of a plot.

If this doesn't fit your application, you might check out

[extracting pitch features from audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730133/extracting-pitch-features-from-audio-file)

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748186/2632177) to that question suggests this library: [http://digitalmusics.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/bregman/](http://digitalmusics.dartmouth.edu/%7Emcasey/bregman/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AudioEqualizer` for the frequency info https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.AudioEqualizer-class.html

The Audio track will have the channels and rate information https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc-branch/doc/doxygen/html/structlibvlc__audio__track__t.html

And the `libvlc_media_stats_t` struct has more info as well https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc-branch/doc/doxygen/html/structlibvlc__media__stats__t.html like

```
int     i_read_bytes
float   f_input_bitrate
int     i_demux_read_bytes
float   f_demux_bitrate
int     i_demux_corrupted
int     i_demux_discontinuity
int     i_decoded_video
int     i_decoded_audio
int     i_displayed_pictures
int     i_lost_pictures
int     i_played_abuffers
int     i_lost_abuffers
int     i_sent_packets
int     i_sent_bytes
float   f_send_bitrate
```